# Can't create a Postgres extension for pgaudit

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgresql-extensions

I compiled pgaudit on Windows10 using Visual Studio. I added `shared_preload_libraries = 'pgaudit'` and restarted the server.

When I try to add the extension, I get:

> ERROR: could not find function "pgaudit_ddl_command_end" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/lib/pgaudit.dll.

I see the function in the source code:

```
pgaudit_ddl_command_end(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
```

Comment: I've only experience installing extensions on Linux, but do you have your PostgreSQL `bin` directory in the path? p.s. welcome to dba.se!

Comment: How did you install the extension?

Comment: I used pgAdmin - there is a menu item under the database to create extensions.

Comment: I looked into the dll and the function has a different name than the source - pgaudit_ddl_command_end  gets named pg_finfo_pgaudit_ddl_command_end. I don't know why it's getting renamed.